# R how to merge 2 data frames on 3 columns all with different column names

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to inner join merge two different data sets with different names for the same columns.  I need to merge on three columns.  I checked stackoverflow and other sources but the questions merge on same name data sources for one column.

current code:

```
state <- c('AZ','MD','NY', 'CA', 'FL')
STATE_ID <- c('AZ','MD','NY', 'CA', 'FL')
month <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
MONTH_ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
year <- c(2001, 2002, 2003, 2004)
YEAR_ID <- c(2001, 2002, 2003, 2004)
# note all rates are fake numbers
eduRate <- (7.5, 6.2, 1.3, 9.9, ....)
otherCol <- c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g' ....)
DROPOUT_RATE <- c(1.2, 3.2, 5.3, 1.9, ....)
someOtherCol <- c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g' ....)
anotherCol <- c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g' ....)

data1 <- data.frame(state, month, year, eduRate, otherCol)
data2 <- data.frame(STATE_ID, MONTH_ID, YEAR_ID, DROPOUT_RATE, someOtherCol, anotherCol)

mergeDf <- merge(x=data1, y=data2, 
                    by.x=state, by.y=STATE_ID, 
                    by.x=month, by.y=MONTH_ID,
                    by.x=year, by.y=YEAR_ID)    #  <-- NOT WORKING

mergeDf(x=data1, y=data2, by=c("state","year","month"))  # <-- cannot use because column names per data set different
```

desired output (do not need extraneous columns

```
#merge on state, month and year to get both edu and dropout rates

state, month, year, eduRate, DROPOUT_RATE
AZ      1      2001   7.5       1.2
AZ      2      2002   9.2       3.2
AZ      3      2003   1.3       1.2
...
AL      1      2001   2.5       1.9
AL      2      2002   5.2       1.7
AL      3      2003   4.3       3.4
...
WY      1      2001   2.5       1.9
WY      2      2002   5.2       1.7
WY      3      2003   4.3       3.4
```

thanx for any help in advance.

Comment: Your code cannot be ran by your readers. There are numerous errors. For example, `eduRate <- (7.5, 6.2, 1.3, 9.9, ....)` is not a valid line, nor are the many `....`s. Also, `<-- NOT WORKING` is not a valid way to comment. Use `#` instead, like you have earlier on in your code. And finally, many of your data frames cannot be formed because their elements are of different lengths. Please, post example code that can be ran.

Comment: I typed ... so I dont need to type all 6000 rows.

Comment: You're unlikely to get help if the people trying to help you cannot test that their solutions to your problem work. Please, provide code that your readers can run.

Comment: Can someone else help?  I just need help with the merge statement.  My data frame is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I like the syntax for joining on multiple keys in dplyr from tidyverse.

```
state <- c('AZ','MD','NY', 'CA')
STATE_ID <- c('AZ','MD','NY', 'CA')
month <- c(1,2,3,4)
MONTH_ID <- c(1,2,3,4)
year <- c(2001, 2002, 2003, 2004)
YEAR_ID <- c(2001, 2002, 2003, 2004)
# note all rates are fake numbers
eduRate <- c(7.5, 6.2, 1.3, 9.9)
otherCol <- c('a','b','c','d')
DROPOUT_RATE <- c(1.2, 3.2, 5.3, 1.9)
someOtherCol <- c('a','b','c','d')
anotherCol <- c('a','b','c','d')

data1 <- data.frame(state, month, year, eduRate, otherCol)
data2 <- data.frame(STATE_ID, MONTH_ID, YEAR_ID, DROPOUT_RATE, someOtherCol, anotherCol)


df<- data1 %>%
  left_join(data2, by=c("state"="STATE_ID","month"="MONTH_ID", "year"="YEAR_ID"))
```